# Save data in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently using discord.py rewrite for my discord bot, 
and I want to make a rank system which needs to save user data. 
 I am using Heroku to run my bot 24 hours, so I can't save user data in my computer.
 Otherwise, it won't run 24hrs.
I want to either save data as a json file, or a text file so I can read with python.

```
# user.txt
88
```

or like json,

```
{"username":"user", "levels":"24"}
```

any **solutions**(e.g. using a server) on saving data?
I have viewed thousands of stackoverflow questions and forums,

But still I can't find the answer.

Regards, IQ-tree.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on files on Heroku - it has ephemeral file system, so any file you create can disappear at any time. Use either [PostgreSQL](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) (more docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/heroku-postgres)), or a cloud storage such as Amazon S3 for persistence. (Your use case fits PostgreSQL much better than using a file on cloud storage.)

Comment: again I saw thousands of articles...and docuements and videos on how to use heroku postgre. But i still cant do it

Comment: "I can't do it" is not really an actionable description of a problem. A [example] like "I tried X, and I got a Y error message", or "I wrote X, but then Z happened" would give you a more useful response.

Comment: i did it. i didn't get any error messages, used thousands of ways i could try thanks to that.